# Using Latex-preview in Emacs with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, emacs, auctex, preview

Is there any way to get preview.el to display graphics for units expressed using the macros of siunitx?  I have succeeded in getting equations and tikz drawings displayed in preview-latex, convincing me that my setup for preview.el is correct, but so far units do not get transformed into images.

As an example, when I try to preview `qty{3}{\newton}`,  I would like it to be displayed in Emacs as "3 N", but instead it just appears as "qty{3}{\newton}".  The output of pdfLaTeX does display it correctly.

I'm using Auctex version 13.2.2.  My version of siunitx.el is dated 2023, but doesn't give a version number.  A comment in the file states that it supports siunitx.sty version 3.0.36 of 2021/22/18 [sic].  My version of siunitx.sty is 3.3.9 of 2023-11-14.

*Additional note:*  the preview.el file is dated 2022, but does not appear to contain an explicit version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell preview about the `\qty` macro and the number of arguments it takes with `\PreviewMacro`.  Here a .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[displaymath,textmath,floats,footnotes,sections]{preview}
\PreviewMacro[{[]{}{}}]{\qty}

\begin{document}

Here we go with $a+b=c$ and now with \qty{3}{\newton}.

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

which looks like this within Emacs and preview:
[image]

Check the manual of preview for more details.